# Initializing the state of CUDNN LSTMs

Tags: tensorflow, state, cudnn

I think we may use the following code segment to create a stack of LSTMs and initializes the states of it to be zero.

```
 lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
            hidden_size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)
 cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
 cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf_float32)
```

Instead of using BasicLSTMCell, I would like to use the CUDNN

```
cudnn_cell = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(
          num_layers, hidden_size, dropout=config.keep_prob)
```

In this case, how can I do the same thing as `cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf_float32)` on cudnn_cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition can be found in : [tensorflow cudnn_rnn's code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py)

Regard to initial_states:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    lstm = CudnnLSTM(num_layers, num_units, direction, ...)
    outputs, output_states = lstm(inputs, initial_states, training=True)
```

So you only need to add the initial states besides the embedding inputs.
In the encoder-decoder system, it would look like:

```
encoder_cell = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(num_layers, hidden_size)
encoder_output, encoder_state = encoder_cell(encoder_embedding_input)
decoder_cell = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(num_layers, hidden_size)
decoder_output, decoder_state = encoder_cell(decoder_embedding_input,
                                             initial_states=encoder_state)
```

Here, the `encoder_state` is a `tuple` as `(final_c_state, final_h_state)`. And the shape of both states are `(1, batch, hidden_size)`

If your encoder is bidirection RNN, it would be a like bit tricky, since the output states are now become  `(2, batch, hidden_size)`.

Hence, I use a roundabout way to solve it.

```
encoder_cell = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(num_layers, hidden_size, direction="bidirectional")
encoder_output, (encoder_c_state, encoder_h_state) = encoder_cell(encoder_embedding_input)
fw_c, bw_c = tf.split(encoder_c_state, [1, 1], axis=0)
fw_h, bw_h = tf.split(encoder_h_state, [1, 1], axis=0)
reshape_encoder_c_state = tf.concat((fw_c, bw_c), axis=2)
reshape_encoder_h_state = tf.concat((fw_h, bw_h), axis=2)
encoder_state = (reshape_encoder_c_state, reshape_encoder_h_state)
```

Although I haven't tried many-layers RNN, I think it can also be solved in a similar way.

Comment: example passing `initial_states` to a bidirectional layer here https://github.com/neqkir/Bible-like-text-generation/tree/main/char-based